# Find Network connection Details in Ionic Application

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

How to find whether a phone is connected to which network.
Using $cordovaNetwork, we can find whether a user is connected to internet or not.
But i want the details of the network to which user is connected such as wifi name.
Is there any way in cordova we can find this.